# Check if duplicates from javascript list based on multiple conditions

Tags: javascript, duplicates, javascript-objects, arrow-functions

I have a javascript list:

```
[
{'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':1},
{'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':2},
{'firstname':'Lisa', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':3},
{'firstname':'Lisa', 'lastname':'Jonas', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':4}
]
```

The first two object are duplicates even though index is different.

I just need to know (boolean) if there are dupes in the list, ie. if firstname and lastname and address is same as some other object in the list.

Is there a smart way to write an arrowfunktion that handles this?

/Per

Answer (score 4):

Using `Array.reduce`, you can extract the duplicate information as follows.

```js
const input = [
  {'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':1},
  {'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':2},
  {'firstname':'Lisa', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':3},
  {'firstname':'Lisa', 'lastname':'Jonas', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':4}
];

const duplicates = input.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  const key = `${cur.firstname}_${cur.lastname}_${cur.address}`;
  acc[key] ? acc[key]++ : acc[key] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});

const hasDuplicates = Object.values(duplicates).some(count => count > 1);
console.log(hasDuplicates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could go through the object and compare all the properties except the one that is `"index"` This way, if you put more properties in the future the code will still work.

You should do something like this:

```
var a = [
{'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':1},
{'firstname':'John', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':2},
{'firstname':'Lisa', 'lastname':'Smith', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':3},
{'firstname':'Lisa', 'lastname':'Jonas', 'address': 'street 1', 'index':4}
]
var l = a.length;
for (var k = 0; k < l; k++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        if(k == i) break;
        var gonnaBeEqual = true;
        for (var prop in a[i]) {
            if (a[k][prop] != a[i][prop] && prop != "index") {
                gonnaBeEqual = false;
            }
        }
        if (gonnaBeEqual) console.log("the object number "+(k+1)+" and the object number "+(i+1)+" are equals")
    }
}
```

In the `if` inside the `for`s, I do a `prop != "index"`, because I don't want it to compare the property of `index`.

The two fist `for`s do the comparing thing, while the third `for` does the access to the property of the object.

The last `if`, the one with gonnaBeEqual, checks if some property wasn't equal, and if there is just one that it was not, it's `false`.